# web.config transform xml element

Tags: xml, web-config, transform

I'm getting rid of web.config configuration batch file (Hanselman's) and want to use the config transformation feature in vs2010. However I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out of to transform an xml element (as opposed to an attribute on an element).

This is a snippet from my web.config:

```
<Federation type="..." xmlns="...">
      <SigningCertificate .../>
      <AllowedAudienceUris>
               <Audience>https://audience.url.com</Audience>
      </AllowedAudienceUris>
</Federation>
```

I want to transform the  element by inserting a different url based on the build configuration - can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

/Jasper

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One approach would be the following:

```
<!-- Copy all nodes -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Operate just on the AllowedAudienceUris (copy it), setting the Audience element -->
<xsl:template match="/Federation/AllowedAudienceUris">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Audience>https://hello.com</Audience>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @jaspernygaard The solution is assuming that the root element is /Federation. You would need to adapt it to what the true xml structure is. You can always post a more complete picture of the problem.

Comment: @jaspernygaard I don't understand... the question is asking about Web Config Transform which is based on XDT, not XSLT.  The code snippet provided in this answer is clearly XSLT.  How is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

If the AllowedAudienceUris and Audience elements occur only once, omitting the `xdt:Locator` is also fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <Federation>
    <AllowedAudienceUris xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <Audience>https://example.com</Audience>
    </AllowedAudienceUris>
  </Federation>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the `xdt:Locator` and `xdt:Transform` attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <Federation>
    <AllowedAudienceUris
        xdt:Transform="Replace"
        xdt:Locator="Condition(//Audience)">
      <Audience>https://example.com</Audience>
    </AllowedAudienceUris>
  </Federation>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It seems like this should work, but it doesn't, as far as I can tell.